# Merge all layers become a single layer in WMS

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, layers, merge, leaflet.wms

I am using ArcGIS Server now to create my WMS, but my WMS has many layers and I use another program (The Leica Spider Business), it can add the WMS in the basemap, but you just can choose only one layer for the WMS.

Is there any method to merge all layers become a single layer for WMS?

Comment: Give a list of layers as a `&layers=` parameter of the GetMap request.

Comment: For a base map you generally only want one layer, requesting multiple layers for the base map means that layers will draw on top of each other (as one image) and this might not be what you want.